# replace placeholder-character in csv-column to newline in output-file (with python)

Tags: python

I have to write code contained in a column of a csv file into new files (from each row). 
Of course, the codes should actually contain line breaks, so I inserted a placeholder character (@) which I want to convert to newline when outputting the new file. I tried to do a replace at various positions in the code, but nothing works. I did not even get to replace @ with an \r\n string. In my last version (below), python simply happily continues to output the @:

```
import csv
import codecs


tablelist=('gz_categoria', 'gz_cabildo')
counter=0
for item in tablelist:
    with open('C:/Hgis/'+"%s" % (item)+'.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        for row in reader:
            row[1].replace('\r\n', '\\r\n')
            row[1].replace('@', '\\r\n')
            newpage = codecs.open ('C:/Hgis/db/'+"%s" % (item)+''+str(counter)+'.txt',encoding='utf-8', mode='w+')
            newpage.write(row[1].decode('UTF-8'))
            counter = counter+1
            newpage.close()
```

Here are the first two lines from the csv:

1,---- dataentry categoria ----@ID: 1000135categoria: Ciudad@subcategoria: Ciudad@es parte de: @Desde: 1539@Hasta: 9999@Desde_fuzzy: exact@Hasta_fuzzy: end@----,1000135,Patzcuaro,1539,exact,9999,end,Ciudad,Ciudad,gerhardNE,None,No,-2

2,---- dataentry categoria ----@ID: 1000136categoria: Pueblo@subcategoria: Pueblo de indios@es parte de: @Desde: 1111@Hasta: 9999@Desde_fuzzy: start@Hasta_fuzzy: end@----,1000136,Puruandiro,1111,start,9999,end,Pueblo,Pueblo de indios,tanck,None,No,0

Desired output in file 1:

---- dataentry categoria ----

ID: 1000135

categoria: Ciudad

subcategoria: Ciudad

es parte de:

Desde: 1539

Hasta: 9999

Desde_fuzzy: exact

Hasta_fuzzy: end

---

Comment: Sorry, I'm a muppet.  You need to _assign_ the result of `str.replace` to a variable, it doesn't change the original in-place: `row[1] = row[1].replace('@', '\\r\n')`

Comment: I have no idea what a muppet is, but it has to be something good. You solved my problem, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, as @snakecharmerb commented, the error was not assigning a variable to the result:

The following code produces the desired result:

```
tablelist=('gz_categoria', 'gz_cabildo')
counter=0
for item in tablelist:
    with open('C:/Hgis/'+"%s" % (item)+'.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
        for row in reader:
            row[1].replace('@', '\r\n')
            newpage = codecs.open ('C:/Hgis/db/'+"%s" % (item)+''+str(counter)+'.txt',encoding='utf-8', mode='w+')
            newpage.write(row[1].decode('UTF-8'))
            counter = counter+1
            newpage.close()
```